# Horizontally Center elements inside the div

Tags: html, css

So i need to create layout with 3 or 4 squares centered in it. As now many different screens are (i at the moment have 21 philips, macbook 13 and ipad) and on all of them the squares are different.

[image: PAGE]

So i need it centered in any screens. Here some of my code:

Some CSS:

```
#main{
border: 1px solid red;
margin: auto;
}
#block{
display: inline-block;
padding: 110px;
border: 1px solid red;
margin: 10px 10px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Some HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
header
</div>
<div id="main">
<div id="block">main</div>
<div id="block">main</div>
<div id="block">main</div>
<div id="block">main</div>
<div id="block">main</div>
<div id="block">main</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried different ways with some extra div... 
[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14396564/screens/Title%20%2820120530%29.png]
[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14396564/screens/Title%20%2820120530%292.png]
[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14396564/screens/Title%20%2820120530%29_new.png]

So i need that this squares would automatically centered in any screens

Comment: Multiple elements sharing the same `id` makes your HTML invalid. Use a `class` instead; an `id` ***must*** be unique within the document.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're just using `inline-block`, you can center the text of the container.

Also, use classes for non-unique elements.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LWTNB/3/

Updated HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        header
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="block">main</div>
        <div class="block">main</div> 
        <div class="block">main</div> 
        <div class="block">main</div> 
        <div class="block">main</div> 
        <div class="block">main</div> 
        <div class="block">main</div> 
        <div class="block">main</div> 
        <div class="block">main</div> 
        <div class="block">main</div> 
        <div class="block">main</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated CSS:

```
#main{
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center; /* solution */
}

.block{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:110px;
    border:1px solid red;
    margin:10px 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Crap, done doing the Fiddle example and here's your answer, +'d this! Ps: remove the `<div style="clear:both"></div>`, it is useless there, and remove the `margin:auto;`, also useless!